# DocuSign API - What is the Default Height for a Text Tab

Tags: docusignapi

I'm adding a Text Tab to a document and playing around with the width and height values. I would like to start with the same height as the default height for a text tab that appears when you don't specify a height value like in this screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know what the value for the default height for a text tab is, or if there's an easy way to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

22 pixels. That's what I got when I just tried.

Comment: I tried 22 pixels but it seems too tall. Changed it to 14 pixels which seems to be a better match for the default height. Are you able to add a screenshot of what it looks like for you when set to 22 pixels? I can't add images to a comment

Comment: turns out the number varies based on the document, so if 14 works for you - that's great.